# Angular2 multiple ngFor for single row

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

I am trying to display a table with values. Table has 5 columns, and in the 3rd column, I need value from another table. How can I implement this?

My html markup is:

list.component.html

```
<table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> first </th>
                    <th> second </th>
                    <th> Third </th>
                    <th> Fourth </th>
                    <th> fifth </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of items">

                    <td> {{item.name}}</td>
                    <td> {{item.subject}}</td>
                    <td *ngFor="let list of details">
                        {{list.firstName}}{{list.lastName}} ----> problem is here  next 2 tds are not displaying the values properly
                    </td>
                    <td> {{item.fisrt}}</td>
                    <td> {{item.second}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My item array

```
items[{name:"", subject:"", first:"", second:""}, {name:"", subject:"", first:"", second:""}]
```

My list array

```
  list[{firstName:"abc", lastname:"pqr"}{firstName:"abc", lastname:"pqr"}]
```

in the first two columns, the values are from one table, and the third column has a value from another table; the remaining two columns have the data from first table again.

How should I implement this?

Comment: Please, post plunker.

Comment: This is not really an Angular2 question. It is much more general.

Comment: the details is part of a item?i mean every item have details?

Comment: i think instead of put the 2nd ngFor in td, create some div or span inside td  and loop so you table structure will not broke

Comment: If you truly want to expand the table horizontally as needed depending on the length of details you could fill the table based on the length of details. If it varies per row, you can still use this approach by getting the max length up front. If your data is paged/scrolling asynchronous data it will be much harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you require a nested table here in your case:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td> {{item.name}}</td>
    <td> {{item.subject}}</td>
    <td>
      <table>
         <tr>
           <td *ngFor="let list of details">{{list.firstName}} {{list.lastName}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td> {{item.fisrt}}</td>
    <td> {{item.second}}</td>
</tr>
```

---

I got the issue you are facing. i have created a [demo @ plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SR84rGecdTI0Uhv3dzIZ?p=preview).

The problem is you are having two objects in the items array so it loops two times for each object.

Comment: And you can adapt this approach easily to work with React, with Aurelia, with AngularJS, or heck just plain old JavaScript. This is a nice and direct solution.

Comment: one more problem am facing in this is the same cell display the value 2 times like "abcpqr" is two time displaying in the third column first row. how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: make a space between them: `{{}} {{}}` and give a width to the td element.

Comment: oh no no that's not actually i meant. i mean my result is now "abcpqr" "abcpqr" in the same cell. ie, 2 values in single cell

Comment: well well how come you got your name changed. woaaah.

Comment: @NidhiMalhotra then you can put this on tr element then.

Comment: i give like this <td>
      <table>
         <tr *ngFor="let list of details">
           <td >{{list.firstName}} {{list.lastName}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table> but the result is same only difference is one name disaplying below the name like "abcpqr"                                                                                    abcpqr

Comment: _make a space between them: {{}} {{}} and give a width to the td element._ did you tried it giving width to the td(parent) element.

Comment: yes i tried but the result is same. in a single cell i got 2 values at a time ie firstnameand lastname printing 2 times

Comment: @NidhiMalhotra added a plnkr for you.